# AT&T x86 | What does `xadd %eax, (%ecx)` do?

Tags: x86, att

Does it exchange `%eax` and `value stored at address%ecxx` and store the sum in `address%ecx`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instruction [`XADD`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/xadd) ...

> ...Exchanges the first operand (destination operand) with the second operand (source operand), then loads the sum of the two values into the destination operand.

So, according to its **Operation**, it executes the following microcode:

```
TEMP ← SRC + DEST;
SRC  ← DEST;
DEST ← TEMP;
```

In your case this means that `xadd %eax, (%ecx)`

- Creates a **TEMP** variable containing the addition of the value of `EAX` plus the value at the address pointed to by `ECX`
- Moves the  value at the address pointed to by `ECX` to `EAX`
- Moves the **TEMP** variable to the address pointed to by `ECX`

This instruction can be combined with a `LOCK` prefix and hence be executed atomically.